# ion-content and ion-footer have different $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I have two input fields inside my ion-content and they both have an ng-model attached to them. Then inside my ion-footer I have an ng-click where I call a function and pass in the two ng-models.

This all worked fine when I had the ng-click inside the ion-content, but when I move it to the footer I get undefined for the two parameters I pass to the function.

So does this mean that ion-content and ion-footer have different $scope's? Even though they're in the same file and have the same controller??

Comment: create a scope like `$scope.data = {}` & place all ng-model which are binded on html.place in this object like `ng-model="data.model1"`,  `ng-model="data.model2"`

Comment: @pankajparkar awesome! Works like a charm! But I'm still curious as to why it wasn't working the way it was? Do content and footer have different scopes in the case of ng-model where I don't have a predefined variable in my controller? Just curious.

Comment: I believe ion-content & ion-footer do create a child scope..& as you declared `$scope.data = {}` in your controller & do access its inner property of it..that will do inherit scope from parent..should I add answer?

Comment: @pankajparkar yeah go for it, cause you're the one that solved my problem!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe `ion-footer` & `ion-content` creates new child scope which is [**Prototypically inerherit**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) from current scope. Below ionic code will give you better illustration that how it works internally, the `scope: true,` is responsible for creating a new child scope.

**Code**

```
.directive('ionContent', [
  '$parse',
  '$timeout',
  '$ionicScrollDelegate',
  '$controller',
  '$ionicBind',
function($parse, $timeout, $ionicScrollDelegate, $controller, $ionicBind) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    require: '^?ionNavView',
    scope: true, //<-- this creates a prototypically inerherited scope
    template:
    '<div class="scroll-content">' +
      '<div class="scroll"></div>' +
    '</div>',
```

You need to use `.` annotation will fix your problem

Eg.

If you are using variable as primitive like

```
$scope.volume = 5
```

Then you need to use:

```
$scope.data = { 'volume' : 5}
```

[**Angular Prototypal Scope Inheritance**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

Answer (score 4):

Explanation of the answer in the comments by pankajparkar:

the ion-content directive has its new scope. It works using the dot notation (important when dealing with scope inheritance)

That is why it works with ng-model="data.model1

Please refer to:

[AngularJS documentation on scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

[Egghead video](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-the-dot)