# Accessing input field from Angular controller results in undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, prototypal-inheritance

So I have a search box that I enter text into then submit, this should send the data to my Angular controller and allow me to access it however I'm just getting undefined when doing so.

The issue is caused when trying to access the field by using $scope.searchtext

My code is as follows:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('SearchCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $ionicLoading) {

$scope.results = [];

$scope.search = function () {
    $ionicLoading.show({ template: 'Loading...' });

    $http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=' + $scope.searchtext + '&key=').
        then(function (data) {

            var searchResults = data

            angular.forEach(searchResults.data.items, function (val, i) {

                $http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,contentDetails&id=' + val.id.videoId + '&key=').
                then(function (data) {

                    var durationResults = data
                    var duration = durationResults.data.items[0].contentDetails.duration.replace("PT", "").replace("H", ":").replace("M", ":").replace("S", "")

                    $scope.results.push({ thumbnail: val.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url, title: val.snippet.title, channel: durationResults.data.items[0].snippet.channelTitle, description: val.snippet.description, duration: duration })
                });

            });
        });

    $ionicLoading.hide();
};

})


<ion-view title="Search for Music">

    <ion-content scroll="true" class="has-header padding">

        <form ng-submit="search()" class="list list-inset">
            <label class="item item-input">
                <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
                <input type="search" name="searchtext" ng-model="searchtext" placeholder="Search">
            </label>
        </form>

        <ion-list>
            <ion-item ui-sref="home" ng-repeat="result in results" class="item item-thumbnail-left">
                <img src="{{result.thumbnail}}">
                <h2>{{result.title}}</h2>
                <strong>{{result.channel}}</strong>
                <p>{{result.description}}</p>
                <p>Duration: {{result.duration}}</p>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ion-content` does create child scope dealing with that DOM, In that case you can use [**AngularJS Prototypal inheritance**](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).

**Code**

```
.directive('ionContent', [
  '$parse',
  '$timeout',
  '$ionicScrollDelegate',
  '$controller',
  '$ionicBind',
function($parse, $timeout, $ionicScrollDelegate, $controller, $ionicBind) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    require: '^?ionNavView',
    scope: true, //<-- this creates a prototypically inherited scope
    template:
    '<div class="scroll-content">' +
      '<div class="scroll"></div>' +
    '</div>',
```

Do follow dot rule while declaring `ng-model` like define `searchtext` as an object property that will tend to follow javascript prototypal.

**Markup**

```
<input type="search" name="searchtext" ng-model="model.searchtext" placeholder="Search">
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.model = {};
```

Similar [**SO answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30189022/2435473) here

Comment: Ah I see, apologies, I'm new to Angular. That's fixed my issue!

Comment: @TomWilson np..Glad to help you..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use can also use **$parent** to access the value of controller.

```
<input type="search" name="searchtext" ng-model="$parent.searchtext" placeholder="Search">
```