# <ion-footer-bar> ng directives and attributes work when footer-bar inside ion-content but

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

I have this `ion-footer-bar`which works just fine inside the `ion-content`, the problem is it isn't sticked to bottom as a footer should be:

```
<ion-footer-bar class="foot-bar" ng-hide="isKeyboardOpen">
  <button class="button button-block btn-policy ion-ios-arrow-thin-right"
          ng-disabled="(!medsRefundForm.firstSubform.$valid && !MedsRefund.toggleChecked)
            || (MedsRefund.toggleChecked && !medsRefundForm.secondSubform.$valid)"
          ng-click="submit()"></button>
</ion-footer-bar>
```

So when I put it outside of ion-content it sticks to bottom but now the ng-directives don't work I believe it's because they aren't sharing the same scope.

I even tried adding the data, like explained in [egghead video](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-the-dot) and in [this commentary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30120293/4031815) but it didn't work. I also added `data.*` to all present vars in BOTH the `ion-content`and the `ion-footer-bar  such as`isKeyboardOpen`, but that didn't fixed the problem.

```
<ion-footer-bar class="foot-bar" ng-hide="data.isKeyboardOpen">
  <button class="button button-block btn-policy ion-ios-arrow-thin-right"
          ng-disabled="(!data.medsRefundForm.firstSubform.$valid && !data.MedsRefund.toggleChecked)
            || (data.MedsRefund.toggleChecked && !data.medsRefundForm.secondSubform.$valid)"
          ng-click="submit()"></button>
</ion-footer-bar>
```

Comment: create a demo of your minimum scenario case, http://play.ionic.io/ . Because technically scope should be shared on whole view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ion-footer-bar` must be placed outside the content.
If you're using `<ion-nav-view>` it has to be placed outside that.

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
  <h1 class="title">Header</h1>
</ion-header-bar>

<ion-nav-view>
  <ion-content>
    Your content here
  </ion-content>
</ion-nav-view>

<ion-footer-bar class="bar-assertive">
  <h1 class="title">Footer</h1>
</ion-footer-bar>
```

It seems that your problem is with your controller. 
What you can do is wrap your html with a `<div>` and define a controller there.

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">

    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">Header</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>

    <ion-nav-view>
      <ion-content>
        Your content here
      </ion-content>
    </ion-nav-view>

    <ion-footer-bar class="bar-assertive">
      <h1 class="title">Footer</h1>
    </ion-footer-bar>

</div>
```

and things should work just fine.

You can check this working sample [here](http://play.ionic.io/app/df7cc10ca161), where I can show/hide the footer bar clicking the button in the content.

Comment: @user912010: Glad I've helped. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on **ionic-2** then the above code may not work as it won't for my case.

See how I got it done-

```
<ion-footer class="bar-stable some-class">
  <center class="some-class">
  <img (click)="scrollTo()" src="img/iamge.png" width="32" height="32">
  </center>
</ion-footer>
```

And I have-

[image]

Hope it will work for you too.