# Ionic Framework: $scope is undefined in simple alert

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope

```
.controller('newGoalCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopup) {
    $scope.addNewGoal = function() {
        alert($scope.goaltitle);
    };
});

<ion-pane view-title="goal">
   <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
      <div class="buttons">
          <a nav-transition="android" class="button button-icon icon ion-arrow-left-b" ng-click="" href="#/index"></a>
      </div>
      <h1 class="title">Add New Goal</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>


    <ion-content class="padding" scroll="false" >
        <div class="list">
            <label class="item item-input">
                <input type="text" placeholder="#Title" ng-model="goaltitle">
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="hashtag-title">#{{hashtagname}}</span>
            </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
              <textarea placeholder="Goal"></textarea>
            </label>
        </div>
    </ion-content>


    <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">
        <button class="button button-positive button-bar no-round-corner" ng-click="addNewGoal()">Add Goal</button>
    </ion-tabs>
</ion-pane>
```

This is my code... I don't know how to explain but it always say undefined when I enter something on the text box...

but $scope.goaltitle = "something" is working on the .controller(); ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short Answer**

> The root cause of this issue is, `ion-content` does create a prototypically inherited child
>   scope, that's why `goaltitle`(primitive type) of controller scope is different than the `goaltitle` you are using on `ng-model`

Ideally practice is to follow `dot rule` while defining view model. So that prototypal inheritance rule will get followed with scope hierarchy.

You should define object and then do assign all the `ng-model` property in it.

**Controller**

```
.controller('newGoalCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopup) {
    $scope.model = {};
    $scope.addNewGoal = function() {
        alert($scope.model.goaltitle);
    };
});
```

Then have `goalTitle`, `Goal`, etc. property in it.

**Markup**

```
<ion-content class="padding" scroll="false" >
    <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="#Title" ng-model="model.goaltitle">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="hashtag-title">#{{hashtagname}}</span>
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <textarea placeholder="Goal" ng-model="model.Goal"></textarea>
        </label>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

I don't want to re-write whole explanation again, so here I'm referencing [**similar answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30189022/2435473), where I've covered all detailed information.

Comment: This worked... but with some changes... alert($scope.model.goaltitle);

Thank you very much... :D

Comment: @MansonMamaril obviously that should be that only.. Glad to help you.. Thanks :)

Comment: Does this method work between controllers?

I need to have a div pinned to the top. But the buttons/inputs in that div need to pass data to another controller? Should I just use $rootScope variables in that case or is there another method?

Does Ionic v1 have a method to pin a div to the top of the screen - I see in other threads methods like ion-fixed but I think thats specific to Ionic 3x and higher. Not certain though. This would all be a lot easier if there was a v1 method to pin a div.

Answer (score 0):

For the html

```
<input type="text" placeholder="#Title" ng-model="foo.goaltitle">
```

JS:

```
$scope.foo = {{
    goaltitle : ''
}}
```