# "ng-click" not working out of "ion-content" in Ionic framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I have an input box with the ng-model attribute in my **ionic** based application. The code inside the `ion-content` tag:

```
<ion-content class="padding">
  <input ng-model="myNumber" type="number" placeholder="Enter number">
</ion-content>
```

And in the **footer-bar**  I have this:

```
<div class="bar bar-footer bar-balanced" style="background-color: #00368C !important; color: #fff;">
    <div class="title">
      <button ng-click="submit(myNumber)" class="button button-clear">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The alert result is **undefined**.

**NOTE:** when I put the `button` inside the `ion-content` it works fine. (It means js codes works fine)

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason behind your problem is, [`ion-content` directive does create a child scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30189022/2435473) which is prototypically inherited from the parent scope. So by placing `myNumber` in input `ng-model` does get added inside the scope of `ion-content`, which is different that the controller `myNumber` number scope variable.

To make it working you need to follow `dot rule` while defining `ng-model`, so that prototypal inheritance rule will get follow(it works on reference type variable). 
So create an new object inside a controller and do assign all ng-model variable into it. like below

```
$scope.model = {};
```

And then put all the properties you wanted to use on view like `$scope.model.myNumber` & while using it on view use it like `model.myNumber`

**Markup**

```
<ion-content class="padding">
  <input ng-model="model.myNumber" type="number" placeholder="Enter number">
</ion-content>

<div class="bar bar-footer bar-balanced" style="background-color: #00368C !important; color: #fff;">
    <div class="title">
      <button ng-click="submit(model.myNumber)" class="button button-clear">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Detailed explanation can be found in [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36177762/2435473)

More elegant way of doing it would be using `controllerAs` approach.

Comment: @vahidnajafi glad to help you.. Thanks :-)

Comment: @PankajParkar - I need to do a similar thing, pin a DIV to the top of the screen and allow `ion-content` to scroll behind it.  But I need buttons and input in the DIV to pass to the controller that controls the `ion-content` view.  How can the above example be adapted to what I need?  I am using Ionic v1

Comment: @PankajParkar - in your example, if you add an `id="divID"` to the DIV, how can you access the DOM with document.getElementById('divID') from the controller that manages the `ion-content` ?  When I try to manipulate the style of the DIV I get a JS error `cannot read property style of null` - I didn't think DOM elements were constrained per ion-view, but it appears it is.

Answer (score 0):

A better and simpler solution, use `<ion-header-bar>` or `<ion-footer>` and place all your pinned content in there - and then keep all your code in the same controller.

Referenced from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51785866/2036221