# Toggle item on Ionic after click on button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to figure out why this toggle on Ionic with Angular doesn't work. I think that the scope of ion-nav-buttons and ion-content are conflicting.

```
<ion-view view-title="Movimentação">
     <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button class="button button-icon" id="header-filter" ng-click="showFilters = showFilters ? false : true">
            <i class="icon ion-search"></i>
        </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>

    <ion-content>
        <ul class="list" ng-show="showFilters">
            <label class="item item-input item-select">
                <div class="input-label">
                    CRAAI
                </div>
                <select>
                    <option ng-repeat="item in craai"> {{ item.regiao }} </option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </ul>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: JS code please. And I do not see a toggle.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36177762/2435473) will help you. also look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30189022/2435473) for more details