# Incrementing Variable in Interval breaks Data Binding

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

All I am doing is increment a number inside an interval. This works till 600 and then the view stops updating(the variable still updates in the background). If I decrease the time of interval to 500 the increment value goes upto 1200 which makes me think its something time related that is causing this behavior. The actual variable keeps increasing but the binding breaks and the view does not get updated.

```
app.controller('testCtrl', function($state, $scope, $cordovaSQLite,  $filter, $timeout,$ionicHistory){

setInterval(function(){

      $scope.u_stepCount += 200;
      console.log( $scope.u_stepCount );
    }, 1000);

});


<ion-view title="Test">
 <ion-content class="dashboard-background">
   <p id="steps">{{u_stepCount}}</p>
   <p id="test_steps"></p>
  </ion-content>  

</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of things

1. You should use `$interval` service instead of `setInterval`, which will take care of running digest after each time function callback gets called.
2. Do follow `Dot rule` while defining `ng-model` as [**ion-content directive create a prototypically inherited child scope**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30189022/2435473). like `$scope.model = { u_stepCount: 0 }` **OR else** you could use controller as pattern while defining controller. Where you will get rid of `$scope` from controller and will have `this`(context) exposed to view binding.

Collectively your code changes will appear to be like below.

**HTML**

```
<ion-view title="Test">
 <ion-content class="dashboard-background">
   <p id="steps">{{model.u_stepCount}}</p>
   <p id="test_steps"></p>
  </ion-content>  
</ion-view>
```

**Code**

```
//removing other dependency that you had just to make code cleaner
//you can have it there if you needed in your actual codebase
app.controller('testCtrl', function($state, $scope, $interval){ //<-inject $interval here
    $scope.model = { u_stepCount: 0 };
    $interval(function(){
      $scope.model.u_stepCount += 200 ;
      console.log( $scope.u_stepCount );
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result ,use  $scope.apply

```
setInterval(function(){
  $scope.$apply(function () {
      $scope.u_stepCount += 200;
       console.log( $scope.u_stepCount );

    }, 1000);
});
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/zBmLmj

Recommended way to achieve same result is using $interval

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$interval) {
  $scope.u_stepCount=0;
$interval(function(){
       $scope.u_stepCount += 200;
       console.log( $scope.u_stepCount );

    }, 1000);

});
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/rLqAQG

Comment: yes Pankaj , i just to make the OP post working and updated with recommended and best way to achieve it :)   Thanks Pankaj