# not getting textbox value using ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am getting an `undefined` when getting the value of the textbox which i weird because i have done this perfectly in my other controller. I am missing something or what

```
app.controller('expandCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
  $scope.get_logged_status = sessionStorage.getItem('logged_status');
  console.log('Expand Message Logged Status: ' + $scope.get_logged_status);
  if($scope.get_logged_status == 'false')
  {  window.location ='#/login'; }

  $scope.getPassedId = sessionStorage.getItem('passedId');
  $scope.getPassedFrom = sessionStorage.getItem('passedFrom');
  $scope.getPassedMessage = sessionStorage.getItem('passedMessage');

  $scope.sendReply = function(){
    console.log($scope.txtReply); <----- HERE!
  }

})
```

my html

```
<ion-view cache-view="false"  view-title="{{ getPassedFrom }}">
  <ion-pane>
    <br><br><br>
    <div class="padding">
        <p>{{ getPassedMessage }}</p>

        <div class="list list-inset">
            <ion-item>
                <textarea rows="5" style="resize:none" ng-model="txtReply"></textarea>
            </ion-item>
            <button class="button button-block button-energized" ng-click="sendReply()">
              Reply
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </ion-pane>
</ion-view>
```

EDIT: i have tried declaring $scope.txtReply =''; and logging as this.txtReply still it returns null;

Comment: I'm not an ionic expert but I supposed (based on documentation) that ion-item directive create isolate or child scope.
Try in your controller to declare an object that contains txtReply: $scope.values = { txtReply: '' } and bind it to ng-model. ng-model="values.txtReply"

Comment: Thank you sir! it worked. i will further read and  understand the documentation now

Comment: You have to use either dot rule while defining models or controller as pattern, please go through [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30189022/2435473) for more explaination