# Can't access data from ion-content in ion-footer

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

**Update**

I get it. I just need to put a

```
$scope.get = {}
```

outside my `save` function and change

```
<button ng-click="save(get)"></button>
```

to this

```
<button ng-click="save()"></button>
```

Thanks to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30119844/ion-content-and-ion-footer-have-different-scope).

---

I have a simple problem that related to access data from `ion-content` in the `button` placed on `ion-footer`. It returns `undefined`.

```
<ion-content>
  <input type="text" ng-model="get.name" />
</ion-content>
<ion-footer>
  <button ng-click="save(get)"></button>
</ion-footer>
```

**js file**

```
$scope.save = function(get){
  alert(get);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JS Code

```
$scope.get = {'Id':1,Name:'Test'};
$scope.save = function (get) {
    alert(get.Name);
};
```

HTML Code

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-content>
        <input type="text" ng-model="get.Name"/>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
<ion-footer>
    <button ng-click="save(get)">Save</button>
</ion-footer>
```

This code will work and alert the **Name**.

Comment: @Emjey23 have you try my solution?